# Jquery not returning the values in form INPUTs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a login form on a modal jquery dialog with the usual 2 text INPUTs.   When I enter a login name and password then click the submit, the call back function is called.

The first thing the callback does is try to extract the values of the two INPUTs, but the values returned are empty strings (I have a breakpont here, and have even stepped through the jquery processing of the objects - they objects are correctly identified as the fields on the form, but `value=""` for both).

At this point I can still see the values in the form, and when the callback exits and the focus goes back to the form, the values are still in the INPUTS. I also tried `.prop("value")` rather than `.val()`, but the result was the same.

I just can't figure why I can't read the values - any help appreciated.

```
<form id="cp-loginform" action="/cypo/index.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" name="Login" value="Login">
    <input type="hidden" name="pp" value="0" />
    <input type="text"  id="cp-loginname" name = "loginname" placeholder = "Login ID" class="loginforminput cp-width-50" autofocus >
    <input type="password" id="cp-password"  name = "password"  placeholder = "password" class="loginforminput cp-width-50"></p>
    <input type="submit" id="cp-submit"  name = "submit" onclick="ProcessLogin()" ></p>
</form>
```

```js
function ProcessLogin() {
    var loginval = $("#cp-loginname").val(); 
    var passwordval = $("#cp-password").val(); 
    console.log(loginval.concat(" ",passwordval));
}
```

PROBLEM RESOLVED:
I felt that this was a scope issue. The form itself was obviously OK (if submitted from the dialog it worked) - it was just the attempt to check the INPUT values using jquery that wasn't working.

I found that my select had to start with the dialog element and include a descendent path to my INPUTs. It's as if the dialog puts a wrapper around the elements inside so they are no longer visible as owned by the document.

If I login with xxx and zzz and step therough the following code I see this:

```
var loginval = $("#cploginname").val();                 << = ""
var passwordval = $("#cppassword").val();               << = ""    
var loginval = $("#cp-loginform #cploginname").val();   << = "" 
var passwordval = $("#cp-loginform #cppassword").val(); << = ""
var loginval = $("#cpdialog #cp-loginform #cploginname").val();   << = "xxx"
var passwordval = $("#cpdialog #cp-loginform #cppassword").val(); << = "zzz" 
console.log(loginval.concat(" ",passwordval));
```

I can't say I understand what's going on, but I have a solution so I am happy. Thanks to all who answered.

FINAL WORD
Thanks to @CMedina, I now understand. The form was defined in a hidden DIV at the top of my BODY section, and I passed $("#loginform") to a f() that created the dialog. The dialog was added to the DOM just before the . I had missed the fact that my original form was still in the DOM, so I was referencing that, not the dialog copy. When I included the dialog wrapper in the path, I finally 'found' the second copy.

Comment: jquery included? any error in console?

Comment: No the console has no errors and the values are displayed in watch as ""

Comment: and yes, jquery included and working fine.

Comment: Try using document ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is the type submit (*their natural behavior is to send the form*). Remove the onclick in your button html.

```
<input type="submit" id="cp-submit"  name = "submit">
```

You must add [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent submit the form and do what you want. Add the code JS for the button onclick event

```
$("#cp-submit").on("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var loginval = $("#cp-loginname").val(); 
   var passwordval = $("#cp-password").val(); 
   console.log(loginval.concat(" ",passwordval));
});
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/svjqb2a4/

Comment: I am breaking the code before it gets to the default action. In fact I started using a jquery button and no submit button when I first noticed the problem. I changed to the submit to see if that would help.

Comment: @Nikkorian you have aditional code js in your html? maybe its cause conflict!

Comment: Forgot to say thanks for replying Carlos. Yes I have lots of js on this page, but I am stepping through the code from the time the event is trapped and it goes exactly where I expect it to. As I said to other answers, the problem only arose when I moved the form to the jquery dialog.

Comment: @Nikkorian Try get value of others input outside of modal (to see if it is the whole page)

Comment: Interesting thought @CMedina. Actually I have resolved the problem - see the main question above. It tells me that elements inside the dialog are not in the scope of the document - it's like the dialog hides its internal elements from direct selection. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @Nikkorian it's interesting, this usually happens when you have 2 input with the same id, otherwise it should return value without path. Check this example https://jsfiddle.net/svjqb2a4/1/

Comment: Brilliant @CMedina, you got it. The form was defined in a hidden DIV at the top of my BODY section, and I passed $("#loginform") to a f() that created the dialog. The dialog was added to the DOM just before the </ BODY>.  I has missed the fact that my original form was still in the DOM, so I was referencing that, not the dialog copy. When I included the dialog wrapper in the path, I finally 'found' the second copy.  Thanks for your insight - I have learned something here. I am an experienced programmer, but new to js and jquery. I still have some learning to do it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form id="cp-loginform" action="/cypo/index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="Login" value="Login">
    <input type="hidden" name="pp" value="0" />
    <input type="text"  id="cp-loginname" name = "loginname" placeholder = "Login ID" class="loginforminput cp-width-50" autofocus >
    <input type="password" id="cp-password"  name = "password"  placeholder = "password" class="loginforminput cp-width-50">
    <input type="submit" id="cp-submit" name ="submit" onclick="ProcessLogin(event)">
    </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function ProcessLogin(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var loginval = $("#cp-loginname").val(); 
            var passwordval = $("#cp-password").val(); 
            alert(loginval.concat(" ",passwordval));
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that detailed response, ehsan. Originally I had this form in a hidden div on the page, showing when necessary, and it worked fine then, just as your code does. The problem only started when I moved it to the jquery dialog - I suspect the problem has something to do with the dialog.